# Query to list all users and apply offset condition on it first then other filters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, workflow

By using below query I am getting unwanted results.

```
select *     
from db_user 
where full_name like 'Admin%'    
order by date_created asc 
OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

**Required Results:**

- To get list of all users and apply offset condition on it first then
  other filters like (having 'fullName' and orderBy 'desc').

**Results Getting:**

- List of all users first with filters applied like (having 'fullName'
  and orderBy 'desc') and then offset applied.

How to arrange query flow to achieve the required result ?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  I don't follow your logic.

Comment: We need to see actual sample data, and expected results i.e. given this sample dataset these are the results I want, but these are the results I am getting. You will get the correct answer much faster if you add this.

Comment: @Dale K thanks for your input as it helped me in resolving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
select u.*     
from (select u.*
      from db_user 
      order by id asc
      OFFSET 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY
     ) u
where full_name like 'Admin%'    
order by date_created asc ;
```

Use of `offset` without `order by` doesn't really make sense.  But this *seems* to be what you are asking for.

Comment: Your example help me alot. with just a little modification it is giving required results. see: 



`select *

 from (select *

 from db_user order by id asc OFFSET 5 ROWS FETCH NEXT 250 ROWS ONLY) u

where full_name like 'Touqeer%'

order by date_created desc;`

Comment: added `order by id` clause as `OFFSET` was not working alone without `order by`

Answer (score 1):

You could filter ou the most recent record with row_number, and then apply the condition on the `full_name` in the outer query, sort and limit:

```
select top(10) *
from (
    select d.*, row_number() over(order by date_created desc) rn 
    from db_user 
) t
where rn > 1 and full_name like 'Admin%'
order by date_create desc
```

Or, using `offset`:

```
select *
from (
    select d.*, row_number() over(order by date_created desc) rn 
    from db_user 
) t
where rn > 1 and full_name like 'Admin%'
order by date_create desc
offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only
```

Comment: Is there any way to deal with offset value as mentioned in question ?

Comment: @iUbaid: the way I understand your question, you don't need `offset` anymore: the filter on `row_number()` eliminates the most recent record (which, as far as concerns, was the purpose of your original `offset`).

Comment: I am using offset for pagination purpose and offset's value can also vary. 
Lets say when limit=10 and offset=2 it will fetch List of users and remove first two entries from it and then return next 10 user's list.

Comment: @iUbaid: ok, I see. In that case just `offset 0 rows fetch next 10 rows only` should do it. I updated my answer.